# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my GridView I can see my date column as `mm/dd/yy` normally but when I select a record and assign a string like so

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
string sdate= row.Cells[2].Text; //Date is in Column 2
```

When I output this `sdate` string it returns: `1368309600000`

And If I try to convert it, it doesn't work and I'm trying to select something from a SQL database and I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

**EDIT**: The part in the SQL statement for conversion is:

```
convert(datetime, '" + sdate +"', 101"+")
```

I suspect the problem is in the `sdate` itself but I'm not sure

Comment: show us the code where you convert it please.  Could be a lot of things, I've seen this often when switching from testing environment to production, and the System Time / Date formatting is different.

Comment: The law of parsimony demands asking the obvious: are you sure that you don't have an off-by-one error in your indexing - i.e. `2` meaning the second column, which should really then be `1` with zero-based indexing?  Also, try indexing the date column by its column name if possible to be sure you are assigning the value from the column you intend.

Comment: I'm sure, because I select the `Cells[1]` it returns the proper colum

Comment: What it gives if you try: string value = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;

Comment: Same thing unfortunately

Comment: Is the second cell text only cell or is there a control in it (textbox, etc)? On seperate note I would retrieve the date as a date from the database and let .net handle the formatting.

Comment: Show us your HTML source with GridView code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date string appears to be expressed as the number of milliseconds since *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*. The T-SQL `CONVERT()` function doesn't support this format. So, you could do a conversion to a C# `DateTime` like this...

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
                   .AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(sdate));
```

`1368309600000` converts to `11/05/2013 22:00:00Z` (this is UTC)

Then adjust for local time and reformat the date for your SQL string like this...

```
"convert(datetime, '" + date.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "', 101)"
```

Comment: Yea, It's Epoch time. It's supposed to be 05/12/2013

Comment: According to www.unixtimestamp.com it converts correctly, Im guessing becuase of the time zone.

Comment: @user2321895, ah yes, of course. I've added a call to `ToLocalTime()` to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[ENTRY] set [_DATE] = CONVERT( date  , @_DATE ,103)  where   [NO] = @NO  "
```

important part here is 103 it is for format dd-mm-yyyy
check out your local format.
this problem only rises for people outside America.

Comment: How does `103` help him when his date is in `mm/dd/yy` format? And, BTW, did you mean "America"?